# How to disappear message in 4 to 6 seconds using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I can display the message using javascript/jquery and i have ajax request but that message is not disappearing after some seconds and i want to disappear it.

**My Code**

```
$('#password_change_form').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var saveThis = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/changepassword",
        data: $(saveThis).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $(".success-messages").text("Heslo bylo úspešne zmeneno").fadeIn();

            setTimeOut(function(){
                $(".success-messages").fadeOut('slow');
            },2000);

            $('#password_change_form').trigger("reset");

        },
        error: function (data) {
            $(".error-messages").text("Zadali jste špatné heslo").fadeIn();

            setTimeOut(function(){
                $(".error-messages").fadeOut('slow');
            },2000);

            $('#password_change_form').trigger("reset");
        }

    });
}),
```

I have setup a setTimeOut function but its not working i dont kno where is the issue:
Your help needs here!

Comment: What have you actually *done* to attempt to figure out the issue, i.e. debugging

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the already pointed out simple typo,  jQuery has its own delay() function, simply use: `$(".success-messages").delay(2000).fadeOut('slow')`

Answer (score 1):

You may not need the setTimeout since jquery provides fadeOut which have a signature like this

```
$(selector).fadeOut(speed,easing,callback)
```

In the speed you can either provide time in millisecond or `slow` or `fast`

```
$(".success-messages").fadeOut(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeOut` should be `setTimeout`. Thats All.

Answer (score 0):

Could also use:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(".foo_msg").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
       $(".foo_msg").slideUp(600);
     });  
})
```

mess around with the values to get desired time
also include "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" in your script tag

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code:

```
setTimeOut(function(){
    $(".success-messages").fadeOut('slow');
},2000);
```

**It should be**:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".success-messages").fadeOut('slow');
}, 2000);
```

you can always make use of the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) JS-reference for looking up details about syntax:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQuery delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) and i will do something like this in your case:

```
$('#password_change_form').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var saveThis = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/changepassword",
        data: $(saveThis).serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            var msg = "Heslo bylo úspešne zmeneno";
            $(".success-messages").text(msg).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
            $('#password_change_form').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function (data)
        {
            var msg = "Zadali jste špatné heslo";
            $(".error-messages").text(msg).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
            $('#password_change_form').trigger("reset");
        }
    });
});
```